# Visual Studio 2017 debugger fails connected to a ClearCase mapped drive

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clearcase

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with a ClearCase dynamic view connected to a mapped drive.

Starting a debugger session fails with:

```
Unable to start program filename.exe.  
Operation is not supported.  
Unknown error: 0x80070057.
```

Using a ClearCase snapshot view, the debugging session works as expected, without error message.
Visual Studio 2013 works perfectly fine with a snapshot or dynamic view.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact ClearCase version, as [seen in this `PI45450`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI45450) (project issue, similar but not identical to your case)

> PI45450: RUNNING AN .NET EXECUTABLE IN A DYNAMIC VIEW FAILS WITH RUNTIME ERROR `SYSTEM.ARGUMENTEXCEPTION 0X80070057` (`E_INVALIDARG`)

Recommendation:

> Running the executable by specifying its fully qualified UNC
>   pathname may work, such as

```
 \\view\viewtag\vobtag\<application>.exe
```

In your case, with Windows:

```
 m:\viewtag\vobtag\<application>.exe
```

See if the full path (`M:\...\<application>.exe`) works better with Visual Studio 2017.

Or try and upgrade ClearCase if possible (8.0.1.10+).

Comment: I'm currently running 8.0.1.10.  I was planning on upgrading to .14 in the morning to see if this made a difference.

Comment: I installed CC 8.0.1.14 this morning, which did not fix the problem.  I also ran the .exe from the UNC path with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new ClearCase APAR for this behavior, because it was initially reported only if the CC VS 2017 integration was installed. It actually doesn't need the integration, at least not on Windows 10 with UAC on. The APAR is PI86014, but it may not be visible yet as it's really new.

The issue is specific to Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2015 will open and start the debug session fine, and the debug executables load just fine from a dynamic view.

The integration released in the technote seems to be a little buggy. Perhaps the one in 9.0.0.5 and 9.0.1.1 will behave better.

Comment: Thank you.  As you mention, it is not visible yet.  I will look into this and hope it is the resolution I need.

Comment: It will be, but it may turn out to be a Visual Studio issue and not a CC one. It all depends on how the investigation turns out.