# VS2017 Debug C++ Project in ClearCase Dynamic View

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clearcase, windows-7-x64, trust, dynamic-view

When I open a VS solution hosted on a mapped ClearCase dynamic view, then try to debug one of the C++ projects within it, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to start program 'Y:\[path]\[program].exe'
>   Operation not supported.  Unknown error: 0x80070057.

My environment is setup as follows:

```
Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64
Visual Studio 2017 Professional (Update 2)
ClearCase Explorer 7.1.2.8
ClearCase view mapped to the Y: drive
```

When I open such a solution file in VS 2017, I get the following dialog:

[image]

I know that I can suppress this dialog by un-checking `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Warn user when the project location is not trusted`.  However, the *real* issue that I am trying to fix is that I am unable to run projects that live on a ClearCase dynamic view from within Visual Studio 2017.

I have verified that copying the directory structure from `Y:` to `C:` results in an application that can be debugged.  Does anyone know how to make the ClearCase dynamic view a trusted location?  I have attempted each of the following from within `Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security`, without success:

1. Change all zones to the least restrictive setting (Internet: Medium; Local Intranet: Low; Trusted Sites: Low).
2. Unchecked "Enable Protected Mode" for the Internet zone.
3. Click the "Sites" button for the "Local Intranet" zone, and...
   a. Uncheck "Automatically detect intranet network"
   b. Check "Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones"
   c. Check "Include all network paths (UNCs)"
4. Click the "Sites" button for the "Trusted Sites" zone, and...
   a. Uncheck "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone"
   b. Add "file://view" to "Websites"
   c. Add "file://[server-name]" to "Websites"
   d. Add "file://[fully-qualified-server-name]" to "Websites"

I also tried adding `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` within the `<runtime>` tag of "*%VS2017INSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config*".

Argh!  Does anyone know how to grant full trust to my ClearCase dynamic views, such that Visual Studio will allow me to debug applications from that drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723753/visual-studio-2017-debugger-fails-connected-to-a-clearcase-mapped-drive). The APAR is still being investigated, but again, this may be an issue with Visual Studio itself as the issue is specific to VS 2017.

Comment: This has been resolved in VS 15.5, as reported in APAR [PI86014: CANNOT DEBUG APPLICATIONS IN A DYNAMIC VIEW UNDER VISUAL STUDIO 2017 AFTER INSTALLING INTEGRATION](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI86014) on the IBM website

Answer (score 0):

> I have verified that copying the directory structure from Y: to C: results in an application that can be debugged.

Actually, you could easily use a snapshot view instead of a dynamic one, with the same config spec (and load rules for loading only what you need)

Second, `Y:[path][program].exe'` is a dynamic view path using a subst drive letter Y.

The full actual path is: `M:\myview\path\program.exe`: so try using the very same view, but through the MVFS (MultiVersion FileSystem) `M:\` (mounting point for *all* dynamic view)

Comment: Unfortunately, opening the same project from the M: drive didn't resolve the issue.  I tried to open it from *\\view\\[myview]\\[path]\\[program].exe* as well, but get the same results.  Finally, I tried running VS as administrator, but that also failed.  I plan to use a snapshot view if there is no other solution, but I'm still hopeful that someone knows how to get VS 2017 to play nice with network paths.